# Most appropriate value for MinimumBlobStorageSize?

Tags: best-practices, remote-blob-storage

I've set up RBS on my SharePoint 2010 server and I'm down to the very last step of deciding just how big a file needs to be before it's set in the Blob Store.  There are tons of articles and blog posts about *how* to set it all up, but I have yet to come across any opinions about what the MinimumBlobStorageSize should be set to based on best practices.

Anybody know?  Right now I'm thinking about either 10MB or 16MB.  (My company doesn't use a ton of multimedia files, so the store shouldn't grow to fast.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really one of those "it depends" type of questions.

If you are targeting performance, Accessing files 256KB or LESS is generally better via DB, and anything larger can be externalized.

Plan for RBS: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628583.aspx

In addition to above MS has this whitepaper on SQL performance of RBS: 
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14726

Outside of performance, the way you set really depends on your goal.  If your goal is to move all files larger than 16MB off to slower storage, than 16MB is what you set, but you can see how this is very dependent on your organizations requirements.

Answer (score -1):

16 MB sounds better than 50MB what we have in place. It's about how big of blob you want to shove in SQL Database. With SQL 2008 R2, you could use External BLOB for larger files.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with RBS. The 50MB is the default limit for file uploads. What happens in the backend has no link to the upload of files.